# Compilation error in TestNG test class for JSON to Java objects

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am trying to convert nested JSON to Java objects and perform API testing using restAssured. I have created Java class for JSON objects and test class using TestNG and restAssured. I am getting compilation error (java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Id) in test class while trying to call set method.

Error :
setId (**.Id) in MyPojo cannot be applied to (java.lang.string)

Created 'MyPojo' and 'Id' Java object class for JSON object and TestNG test method : createTestRun

Nested Json:

```
{
"Id":{
    "Status":"PASSED",
    "Message":"Run from restAssured",
    "Number": "123"
     }
 }
```

Class:MyPojo

```
    public class MyPojo
    {
        private Id Id;

        public Id getId ()
        {
            return Id;
        }

        public void setId (Id Id)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "ClassPojo [Id = "+Id+"]";
        }
    }
```

Class: Id

```
    public class Id
    {
        private String Status;

        private String Message;

        private String Number;

        public String getStatus ()
        {
            return Status;
        }

        public void setStatus (String Status)
        {
            this.Status = Status;
        }

        public String getMessage ()
        {
            return Message;
        }

        public void setMessage (String Message)
        {
            this.Message = Message;
        }

        public String getNumber ()
        {
            return Number;
        }

        public void setNumber (String Number)
        {
            this.Number = Number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "ClassPojo [Status = "+Status+", Message = "+Message+", Number = "+Number+"]";
        }
    }
```

Test Class :

```
    @Test
 public void createTestRun() {

    Id id = new Id();
    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();

    myPojo.setId("23685") // Getting Error in this line of code
    id.setSuccess("PASSED");
    id.setConclusion("Run from restAssured");
    id.setRunTime("123");

    Response response = given()
            .auth().preemptive()
            .basic(propertyFile.getUserName(),propertyFile.getPassword())
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .when()
            .body(id)
            .post(ROOT_URI + TEST_RUN_ID + "/result");
            .then()
            .extract()
            .response();
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public void setId (Id Id)` method signature requires the argument to be of type `Id` and not `String`. You are passing a string in the line `myPojo.setId("23685")`.
Change it to `myPojo.setId(id)`